# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'phone' in Model Serializer django rest

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am building a project using Django rest Api.I have a model called DriverProfile now I have to add a driverprofile,but I am getting error below:

**Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `phone`
     on     serializer `DriverProfileCreateSerializer`.The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance. Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'phone'**

I have used APIView and modelSerializer and I don't why it is coming, while phone field is present in DriverProfile.
Important when I do this stuff from generic views instead of APIView it works, but when I use model serializer and API view it throws errors.I guess the error is in create() in model serialzer where I use driverprofile = DriverProfile.objects.all(), I am unable to sort please someone guide.

**Models.py:**

```py
class Driver(models.Model):
    User=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = models.Manager()

class DriverProfile(models.Model):
    driver=models.OneToOneField(Driver,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    drive_name=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=12)
    driver_cnic=models.CharField(max_length=13)
```

**Views.py**

```py
class CreateDriverProfile(APIView):

    def get(self,request):
        return Response([DriverProfileCreateSerializer(driver).data for driver in DriverProfile.objects.all()])

    def post(self,request):
        payload=request.data
        serializer=DriverProfileCreateSerializer(data=payload)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Serializer.py:**

```py
class DriverProfileCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): # create driver profile

    class Meta:
        model=DriverProfile
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        driverprofile = DriverProfile.objects.all()
        return driverprofile

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for k, v in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, k, v)
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 2):

- Change your `DriverProfileCreateSerializer` like this:

```py
class DriverProfileCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): # create driver profile

    class Meta:
        model=DriverProfile
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        driverprofile = DriverProfile.objects.create(**validated_data) # HERE!
        return driverprofile

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for k, v in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, k, v)
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: I have tried this but get this error "  all() got an unexpected keyword argument 'drive_name' ", after adding **validated_data

Comment: Can you show us how your data look like ? Maybe the data keys, you are sending, does not match your python model class fields. @MuhammadNabeel

Comment: Ok got it i added .all(**validated_data) instead of .create(**validated_data).Thanks